# PayPal Payflow api gives error Insufficient permissions to perform transaction

Tags: php, paypal, payflowpro

I am using [PHP Payflow library](https://ccaples.com/chad/pf_sdk_v2/) for payment. Its working fine with the default settings of user name, password and vendor, but when I put my vendor along with an user created at my manager site, I keep getting api error for sale method as:

```
RESULT  52
PNREF   B70P6E0297BE
RESPMSG     Insufficient permissions to perform transaction
```

pnref differs though. When I checked for daily transactions at manager site, all the transaction are listed there with result code as 52.

I tried to create profile of payer for recurring billing, but that too results with code 36 and txnresult code 5 and api error looks like

```
RESULT  36
RPREF   R1056FBB4803
RESPMSG     Transaction failed: Fail to obtain approval for the online transaction
TRXRESULT   5
TRXPNREF    B70P6E02CD90
TRXRESPMSG  Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to make this API call
HOSTCODE    10002
TRANSTIME   2014-09-01 04:12:28
FIRSTNAME   John
LASTNAME    Doe
AMT     3.00
ACCT    1111
EXPDATE     1215
CARDTYPE    0
```

This transaction also listed in daily transactions.

The user I am using for transaction has give `API_FULL_TRANSACTION` permission. I tried to change it to `FULL_TRANSACTION` but the result is same. I also tried the transaction with `ADMIN` permissions, but it also results with code 52.

What kind of permission do we need to set for user to perform the transaction?

Comment: How can I find out whether I have a Payflow Link account or Payflow Pro?

Comment: Hey MG1, Please go through this link. you can find your account status under services tab on your payflow account dashboard https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#who-should-use-this-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the result code = 52 , it seems that you have PayPal advanced account but you are trying to process the Payments directly on your website using the API's that is not allowed because with PayPal advanced you have to use PayPal Hosted checkout Pages . To get rid of this error you must have pro account or use the hosted checkout Pages .

And one more thing if you are in test mode , make sure to put the sandbox account email address in your manager account under Service settings --> Set Up --> PayPal sandbox email address . And this sandbox account should be a Pro account . You can create a sandbox account by logging to developer.paypal.com with your PayPal credentials --> Applications--> Sandbox accounts .

For the recurring billing error , can you post the parameters submitted to the PayPal ?

Comment: the account is pro. is this related with user's permission that need to be set on manage user page?

and for recurring I passed billing info, shipping info, merchant credentials, tender, start date, period, amount etc

Comment: The result code is not related to the user permission under manager user . It definitely has to do with the account . Login to your manager account and check at the home page under service summary . I am sure it should say PayPal Payment Advanced there . This means you don't have Pro account

Comment: yes you are right, the account is not pro. I will ask client for that. mean while, I am not sure, is the recurring billing error is also occurring because the account is pro?

Comment: The recurring billing error should also be due the same reason because  with Paypal advanced you should use the hosted checkout pages and then you can use the transaction id to create the recurring profile but if you want to pass the credit card info while creating the recurring profile you must have pro account.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still having confusion. This account is Paypal advance and not pro, hence it is not working correctly for me, right? Can you please tell me, payflow-pro and paypal-pro are one and the same? or they are both different API's?

Comment: Functionality wise both are same but they are different from the integration perspective . For PayPal Pro(direct edition) you will use the PayPal API's but for PayPal Pro( Payflow Edition) you will use the Payflow API's .

Comment: How can I find out whether I have a Payflow Link account or Payflow Pro?

Comment: Once you login to the manager account , on the home page under "Service Summary" it will show "Payflow SDK/API (Limited Access)" for Advanced and "Payflow SDK/API (Full Access)" for Pro ..

Comment: Exactly this was the cause for my issue.
** Insufficient permissions to perform transaction ***

Credit card information can be entered only with PayPal Pro account

Answer (score 0):

Your Payflow Manager account has to sync with your PayPal Sandbox account. then it is ready to begin accepting Test/Sandbox transactions.

If you do not see the PayPal Express Checkout section on the Set Up page, you will need to contact Merchant Technical Support. Url : `https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1961&expand=true&locale=en_US`